# Searching Kilobytes in Bytes

Tags: php

I have a table with column name = recording_size.
In this column I am storing the size in bytes,
but on the Web I am showing the size in KB.

```
       public static function getKbFromBytes($string){
         if($string){
            return ($string/1024);
          }
       }
```

Now I have a Filtration Functionality in Web. So as I am showing size in KB so I'll certainly take Input for Searching from user in KB & not in bytes although in DB I have that in bytes. For that I take input in KB and than convert it again to bytes like:

```
    public static function getBytesFromKb($string){
        if($string){
         return ($string * 1024);
       }
    }
```

Example:

```
size in Bytes = 127232
```

When I apply my function so it = 124.25 KB
now when user write exactly like 124.25 then the search works,
but I want that user does not write exactly the same.
The user can also write 124 instead of 124.54, and when the user writes 124 then my search is not working — meaning it does not show any records.
I have also ADD & Subtract 50 from the converted bytes but it is not working.

```
   $sql = $sql->where('r.recording_size BETWEEN "'.(Engine::getBytesFromKb($opt['sn']) - 50) .'" AND "'.(Engine::getBytesFromKb($opt['sn']) + 50) .'"');
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for size should probably be as a range instead of an equality anyway. At least, the default should be the range, unless your app's primary focus is the exact size. For the SQL:

```
$kb = round($opt['sn']);
$sql = $sql->where('r.recording_size BETWEEN '.($kb * 1024).' AND '.(($kb + 1) * 1024));
```

By the way, you should omit the quotation marks (`"`). They are invalid/nonstandard even for strings. And you are comparing `int`'s.

Another thing to watch for is KiB vs KB.